# Why does WM_MOUSEWHEEL fire in a WH_GETMESSAGE hook, but not in a WH_MOUSE hook?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, mousewheel

I've set two thread-local hooks (in the context of an Explorer browser helper object), like so:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(   WH_MOUSE,
                    MouseHookProc,
                    NULL,
                    GetCurrentThreadId()  );

SetWindowsHookEx(   WH_GETMESSAGE,
                    GetMsgProc,
                    NULL,
                    GetCurrentThreadId()  );
```

My hook procs look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    switch (wParam)
    {

    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        ATLTRACE("\n WM_MOUSEWHEEL from MouseHookProc \n"); // <-- Does not print on mouse wheel movement
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    LPMSG lpmsg = (LPMSG)lParam;
    UINT msg = LOWORD(lpmsg->message);

    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        ATLTRACE("\n WM_MOUSEWHEEL from GetMsgProc \n");  // <-- Prints on mouse wheel movement
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It appears that only the `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook gets the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message.  Am I doing something wrong, or is that what should happen?  And if that should happen, why?  Thanks for any info.

As a side note, while investigating this, I discovered a bug in Windows (at least on 8.1, using a Synaptics trackpad).  If you select a file in Explorer, then click on the name to initiate the rename timer, and then begin scrolling before the rename control has appeared, the rename control will still appear and just float after you scroll away: [Explorer scroll/rename bug gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luLuS.gif)

Comment: `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` had a predecessor (see [What’s with this MSH_MOUSEWHEEL message?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080806-00/?p=21353)). Maybe there's some compatibility story here. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: Depending on implementation, `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` may be a synthesized message, not an actual mouse event, so it wouldn't show up in a mouse hook, but would in a message hook.

Comment: Oh, is it possible that Synaptics synthesized it or something?  'Cause I'm on a trackpad.

Comment: @loop123123 I can get `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message from both `WH_MOUSE` and `WH_GETMESSAGE` on Windows 10 1909 (build 18363.778). What's your Windows version?

Comment: @loop123123 And also I can't reproduce rename issue on Windows 10 1909 (build 18363.778).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I'm on Windows 8.1, using a Synaptics ClickPad, with two-finger scrolling.

Comment: @loop123123 Windows 8.1 Enterprise (Version 6.3 build 9600) does work for me.